# Alternative for my slow nested loop with if-statement?

Tags: r, if-statement, nested-loops

I got two big data frames (df with 7038 rows and df2 with 14076 rows).
I want to compare them and add values if certain fields are the same.

I tried a nested for loop with an if-statement but it takes several hours to complete.

df:

```
Date       HomeTeam     AwayTeam      FTR   GoalScoreHome GoalScoreAway
   <date>     <chr>           <chr>         <chr> <chr>         <chr>        
 1 1995-08-18 For Sittard     PSV Eindhoven A     NA            NA           
 2 1995-08-19 Go Ahead Eagles Groningen     D     NA            NA           
 3 1995-08-19 Roda JC         Heerenveen    D     NA            NA           
 4 1995-08-19 Willem II       Sparta        H     NA            NA           
 5 1995-08-20 Ajax            Utrecht       H     NA            NA           
 6 1995-08-20 Feyenoord       Vitesse       H     NA            NA           
 7 1995-08-20 Graafschap      Nijmegen      A     NA            NA           
 8 1995-08-20 Volendam        Twente        A     NA            NA           
 9 1995-08-20 Waalwijk        NAC Breda     D     NA            NA           
10 1995-08-23 Groningen       For Sittard   H     NA            NA
```

df2:

```
Round Date        Team   GDPerGame      PointsPerGame      GoalScore5.2
1     1 1995-08-20 Ajax          4             3           NA
2     2 1995-08-25 Ajax          6             3           NA
3     3 1995-09-10 Ajax          4             3           NA
4     4 1995-09-17 Ajax          4             3           NA
5     5 1995-09-20 Ajax          4             3           NA
6     6 1995-09-24 Ajax          1             3           22
```

I'm using the following loop:

```
for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
  for (j in  1:nrow(df2)) {
    if(df$HomeTeam[i] == df2$Team[j] & df$Date[i] == df2$Date[j] ){

      df$GoalScoreHome[i] = df2$GoalScore5.2[j]
    }
    else if(df$AwayTeam[i] == df2$Team[j] & df$Date[i] == df2$Date[j]){
      df$GoalScoreAway[i] = df2$GoalScore5.2[j]
    }

  }

}
```

This works as intended, but as I said before it's way too slow

I found some alternatives for a nested loop, but not with an if-statement in it. Does anyone know a good, faster alternative?

Comment: I suggest you merge the two dataframes and then do computations on the merged dataframe.

Comment: Try working with `dplyr`.  Something like `df %>% left_join(df2, by = c('HomeTeam' = 'Team')) %>% mutate(GoalScoreHome = GoalScore5.2) %>% select(Date, HomeTeam, AwayTeam, FTR, GoalScoreHome, GoalScoreAway) %>% left_join(df2, by = c('AwayTeam' = 'Team')) %>% mutate(GoalScoreHome = GoalScore5.2)`

Comment: I agree with @C.Braun, but I would add 'Date' to `by` on both `left_join` as the combination of 'Team' and 'Date' serves as a unique identifier.

Comment: @C.Braun This worked perfectly without the second left_join and by adding date like Recle Vibal suggested. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest looking into the [merge](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/merge) command.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a merge problem. You could merge two datasets by date first then by team. If you are familiar with SQL, you could use RSQLite package to do it as well, it's even faster.